# How do i integrate an If function within the forEach function with GREL?

Tags: regex, google-refine

i am working with Google Refine right now. My goal is to split a single, existing column into two  parts. I am using the built in "add column based on...“-function. The column contains a street name and the coressponding house number. For example, I've got this:

```
Stackoverflow Street 89
```

Every row is structured in the same way, which means that a streetname can be long or short, can contain one or more words, but it always ends with a (house) number and its always separated by a blank space.

As I am working with Google Refine, i was about to do this by using GREL statements (Google Refine Expression Language). The idea is like that: Split every value divided by a blank space into pieces. Save each split value in a variable. Then check if the specific values contains a numeric value (which is the house number). If it is a numeric value, take that value and forward it to the output. I already got something like this.

```
forEach(value.split(" "), v, v).join(";")
```

Here is the question: How do i integrate an IF function within the forEach function? If i would know how to do it, i would probably be able to not only split the values, but also check if its numeric. To check if it is numeric, one can use isNumeric(value).

I appreciate every hint. Thanks, Jörg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the constraints that you describe hold true (it's always the last piece and always exists), I'd just use `value.split('')[-1]`

In answer to the direct question that you asked, in case someone else finds this in search, your expression so far is equivalent to:

```
value.split(" ").join(";")
```

ie the forEach isn't doing anything.  To integrate the if(), use it as part of the expression which forms the 3rd parameter to forEach

```
forEach(value.split(" "), v, if(isNumeric(v),null,v)).join(";")
```

I'm not sure what output format you're trying to achieve, but this will give you a semi-colon separated list of all non-numeric words in your cell value.

Comment: Thank you, too. Both solutions, halex and Tom Morris, worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Edit column > Split into several columns...`](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/ColumnEditing#Splitting_Columns) on your column and split it with the regex `\s(?=\d+)`, which means that the split has to be where a space character is followed by more than one numbers, and the numbers are not part of the split.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked out exactly like i wanted to.